# Unit testing operator<< in C++

Tags: c++, unit-testing, iostream

I'm trying to figure out a nice way to unit test my implementation of the `operator<<` in C++. I have a class which implements the operator, and given an instance with a specific state, I'd like to check that the output is what I want it to be.

This is my code (the header file):

```
class Date {
    virtual int year() const { return 1970; };
    virtual int month() const { return 1; };
    virtual int day() const { return 1; };
    friend  std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Date &d);
};

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Date &d) {
    os << d.year() << "-" << d.month() << "-" << d.day();
    return os;
};
```

Now, in my unit test method, I could just do `Date d; cout << d;` and verify when I run the tests that the output is correct. However, I'd much rather programmatically verify this, so I don't have to look at the test output more than at the final report (which hopefully says "0 failed tests!").

I'm fairly new with C++, so I've never really used streams for anything but input and output.

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: You shouldn't make it a friend unless it needs to access private members.

Comment: [std::stringstream in the <sstream> header](http://tipsandtricks.runicsoft.com/Cpp/Stringstream.html)

Comment: @chris: I oversimplified a little - but thanks for the heads-up!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use a [`std::stringstream`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/stringstream/) to hold the result, and then call [`str()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/stringstream/str/) on it to get a string:

```
#include "Date.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main() {
    Date d;
    std::stringstream out;
    out << d;
    if(out.str() == "1970-1-1") {
        std::cout << "Success";
    } else {
        std::cout << "Fail";
    }
}
```

Note: I spent quite a while looking for a decent unit testing framework in C++ and the best I found at the time was [googletest](http://code.google.com/p/googletest/) -- in case you haven't picked a framework yet.

Comment: Thanks! This is precisely what I was looking for. We are already using cxxtestgen (a python-based framework), which I didn't choose myself but which is quite sufficient at the moment. Thanks for the tip, though - I'll definitely take a look at googletest the next time I get to choose the testing framework!

Comment: @BrendanLong If you haven't looked recently (within the past month or so), I released a new [unit testing framework](https://bitbucket.org/moswald/xunit) that I believe surpasses gtest. OTOH, if you *have* looked at xUnit++ and still prefer gtest, would you mind letting me know why? I welcome all feedback.

Comment: @moswald Looks really cool. I'll probably try this out in the next situation where I need a new test framework. I like the fact/theory thing.